# Adding a String value to an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I'm removing and adding a certain value from an `ArrayList<String>`. Removing the value is not a problem but when I try adding it again the old contents of the `ArrayList` become a new element at position 1 while at position 0 is the new element making the others inaccessible if I want to remove from them.This is the Log result after adding the new value:

```
[blantyre, ["mzuzu","lilongwe","zomba"]]
```

yet the original looked like:

```
[mzuzu, lilongwe, blantyre, zomba]
```

I have tried the following methods:
`ArrayList.add(0,new String("blantyre")` and `ArrayList.add("blantyre")` but they both take the old contents and place them in position 1.

I am getting the ArrayList from `SharedPreferences` using this statement:

```
ArrayList<String> districts = AppController.getInstance().getPrefManager().getDistricts();
```

Where the `getDistricts` method returns an `ArrayList<String>`.
In the SharedPreference the `getDistricts` method more or less looks like:

```
return new ArrayList<String>() {{
        //return the default districts, which is all of them
        add(AppConst.KEY_MZUZU);
        add(AppConst.KEY_LILONGWE);
        add(AppConst.KEY_BLANTYRE);
        add(AppConst.KEY_ZOMBA);
    }};
```

All the `AppConst.KEY_x` are of type `String`

Comment: Are you sure the original ArrayList doesn't contain an ArrayList element? Please show more code.

Comment: Can you provide a longer code fragment?

Comment: Are you sure, that your `ArrayList` is not an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`?

Comment: I think you're mixing arrays (String[]) with lists (List<T>). The arrays are immutable, once they are initialized you could not extend the length. Lists are dynamic and could be extended bye calling the method *add()*. Anothe thing, you should not use *ArrayList.add()* but use *yourListObjectInstance.add()*.

Comment: I am using the actual object in the code @MarioAlexandroSantini . As you can see I am using ArrayList not arrays.

Comment: You need to post all the relevant code. I don't see the code getting the original list, printing it, adding an element, and printing it again. Also, creating an anonymous ArrayList subclass just to return an ArrayList of 4 elements is horrible. Just create an empty list then add the 4 items. Or use `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1ppConst.KEY_MZUZU, AppConst.KEY_LILONGWE, ...))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following test:

```
package default;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by mario on 21/08/2016.
 */
public class TestArrays {

    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(TestArrays.class);

    private static class AppConst{
        public static final String KEY_MZUZU = "key_mzuzu";
        public static final String KEY_LILONGWE = "key_lilongwe";
        public static final String KEY_BLANTYRE = "key_blantyre";
        public static final String KEY_ZOMBA = "key_zomba";
    }

    public List<String> getDistricts() {
        return new ArrayList<String>() {{
            //return the default districts, which is all of them
            add(AppConst.KEY_MZUZU);
            add(AppConst.KEY_LILONGWE);
            add(AppConst.KEY_BLANTYRE);
            add(AppConst.KEY_ZOMBA);
        }};
    }

    @Test
    public void testOne() {
        List<String> list = getDistricts();

        LOG.info(list);

        list.add("blantyre");

        LOG.info(list);

        assert(list.size() == 5);
    }
}
```

As you can see I used the *List* interface for the variable, even I work with *ArrayList*s.

It is better to use the interface for the variables and method signatures.

The test executes successful with the following output:

```
11:55:19.822 [Test worker] INFO  org.unopercento.feeder.adapters.TestArrays - key_mzuzu
11:55:19.823 [Test worker] INFO  org.unopercento.feeder.adapters.TestArrays - [key_mzuzu, key_lilongwe, key_blantyre, key_zomba]
11:55:19.823 [Test worker] INFO  org.unopercento.feeder.adapters.TestArrays - [key_mzuzu, key_lilongwe, key_blantyre, key_zomba, blantyre]
```

As you can see, if you use the List the results is as expected.

Comment: I wrote a similar test code but using ArrayList instead of List and it still worked as expected. There's something wrong elsewhere in his code.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post adding a comment about the use of interface in method signatures and variables instead to use the class.

Comment: I don't understand but using List instead of ArrayList achieves the desired result...thanks guys

Comment: somewhere in my sharedpref code I use Arrays.asList to retrieve the data, this statement is what is causing problems by doing the wrapping of the objects into 1

Answer (score 1):

**My commentary is,** 
What you did is storing the shared preferences strings in `ArrayList<String>` `list1` and then returned the `list1`to be stored in a general `ArrayList` `list2`(without `<T>`). Then you removed item from `list1` and add it again in `list2`

I regenerated your case in **test1()** and make the correct solution in **test2()**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ArrayListTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    //test1();
    test2();



}

private static void test1(){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        //return the default districts, which is all of them
        add("mzuzu");
        add("lilongwe");
        add("blantyre");
        add("zomba");
    }};

    ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
    list2.add(list);

    list.remove("blantyre");
    list2.add(0,"blantyre");
    System.out.println(list);
    System.out.println(list2);
}

private static void test2(){
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        //return the default districts, which is all of them
        add("mzuzu");
        add("lilongwe");
        add("blantyre");
        add("zomba");
    }};
    System.out.println(list);

    list.remove("blantyre");
    list.add(0,"blantyre");
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

}

**test1 output:**

[mzuzu, lilongwe, zomba]

[blantyre, [mzuzu, lilongwe, zomba]]

**test2 output:**

[mzuzu, lilongwe, blantyre, zomba]

[blantyre, mzuzu, lilongwe, zomba]